# Pentaho data integration multi-select parameter

Tags: mongodb, pentaho-data-integration

I want to pass multiple values to a pentaho data integration transformation in order to filter the final result.if i want to write a sql query all I have to do is :
select field from table  where name in `${parameter}`
the probleme is I want to do the same thing using mongodb queries but I didn't find a way to do it.
If anyone has an idea I would really  appreciate the help.thanks

This is what I thought about,but it stills doesn't work:
`{ Nom_organisation: { $in: ["${organisation}"] } }`

If anyone had expérience with Multi-select paramètres with mongodb I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a Document from your collection?

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you need?

```
db.collection.find({
  "Nom_organisation": {
    $in: [
      "ONEA1",
      "OTHER"
    ]
  }
})
```

An working example at: https://mongoplayground.net/p/u1tnkZo7w5E